# Controller returns HTTP Error 400 Bad Request for a simple GET Request

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, postman

I am trying to test a really simple controller implementation of really simple GET endpoint.

Here is the definition of the endpoint which I am trying to call:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/message
```

End Here is the Java code of the controller:

```
package com.nunit.messaging;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageController {

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Success!";
    }

}
```

By using Postman to send a request to this endpoint I am getting always this HTTP error code 400 Bad Request. Here is a screenshot from Postman:
[image]
[image]
Here is also the Debugger's log from IntelliJ:

```
2022-10-08 14:56:24.794 TRACE [,ca879d2587d1abd8,ca879d2587d1abd8] 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.zalando.logbook.Logbook              : {"origin":"remote","type":"request","correlation":"a1358ca4cd6346ac","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","remote":"127.0.0.1","method":"GET","uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/message","host":"127.0.0.1","path":"/api/message","scheme":"http","port":"8080","headers":{"accept":["*/*"],"accept-encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"cache-control":["no-cache"],"connection":["keep-alive"],"host":["127.0.0.1:8080"],"postman-token":["3acd7713-4802-4220-9696-ad6306dcf0e2"],"user-agent":["PostmanRuntime/7.29.2"]}}
2022-10-08 14:56:24.852 TRACE [,ca879d2587d1abd8,ca879d2587d1abd8] 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.zalando.logbook.Logbook              : {"origin":"local","type":"response","correlation":"a1358ca4cd6346ac","duration":84,"protocol":"HTTP/1.1","status":400,"headers":{"Connection":["close"],"Date":["Sat, 08 Oct 2022 11:56:24 GMT"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"Vary":["Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers"]}}

2022-10-08 14:56:46.612 TRACE [,81a06c6f0d10d7fe,81a06c6f0d10d7fe] 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.zalando.logbook.Logbook              : {"origin":"remote","type":"request","correlation":"b24ead4d840caba9","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","remote":"127.0.0.1","method":"GET","uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/messages","host":"127.0.0.1","path":"/api/messages","scheme":"http","port":"8080","headers":{"accept":["*/*"],"accept-encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"cache-control":["no-cache"],"connection":["keep-alive"],"host":["127.0.0.1:8080"],"postman-token":["11e023e5-04c4-4856-a3e0-4fbf008befcd"],"user-agent":["PostmanRuntime/7.29.2"]}}
2022-10-08 14:56:46.614  WARN [,81a06c6f0d10d7fe,81a06c6f0d10d7fe] 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /api/messages
2022-10-08 14:56:46.615 TRACE [,81a06c6f0d10d7fe,81a06c6f0d10d7fe] 9584 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.zalando.logbook.Logbook              : {"origin":"local","type":"response","correlation":"b24ead4d840caba9","duration":3,"protocol":"HTTP/1.1","status":404,"headers":{"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Date":["Sat, 08 Oct 2022 11:56:46 GMT"],"Keep-Alive":["timeout=60"],"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"Vary":["Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers"]}}
```

The last three lines are just to check that I am calling the correct endpoint and that it is recognized.

I can not figure it out what is causing this Error 400 Bad Request. I am calling the correct URL since debugger is giving a warning when I try to send a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/messages`.

Comment: "No mapping for GET /api/messages" ..is it possible, that your controller (`package com.nunit`) is not "picked up"(component-scanned) ..by your config!?

Comment: @ xerx593: the correct endpoint is /api/message, I gave an example with /api/messages just to eliminate the case where I am not calling it correctly and the annotation @RestController is responsible to mark the class as a web request handler.

Comment: no, I am not using the default package and in the application.yml I haven't configured anything explicitly.

Comment: the endpoint /api/message is found correctly but it returns 400 Bad Request otherwise when I call /api/messages from Postman I get 404 Not Found which is reasonable

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce! (so something about your controller is more complex than described ..web security!?)

Comment: I have created another project and copy/paste the same functionality and there it is working properly even POST/PUT requests but here something is odd.

Comment: I was missing 2 required headers inside the request for the project other than that nothing to change.